# Swap : and ; to make colon commands easier to type in Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24, evil-mode

I just started using emacs with Evil mode. In my `.vimrc` file I had the following:

```
nnoremap  ;  :
nnoremap  :  ;
```

What would I put in my `.emacs` file to achieve the same thing in emacs evil mode?

Comment: Please use your search engine first for questions! This seems to be a pretty basic and common topic. Google "emacs evil remap" for example. And the tag is irrelevant indeed, this has not very much to do with Vim. It is clearly an emacs question. Tag not by "touching" subjects, but by content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [emacs evil equivalent of vim remapping, e.g. :nnoremap dd g0dg$](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421227/emacs-evil-equivalent-of-vim-remapping-e-g-nnoremap-dd-g0dg)

Comment: No, not a dupe of that question. This is a question about a specific remapping - which is surprisingly not well addressed in the obvious searches, since most questions about remapping keys address function keys, not self-inserting keys

Comment: @sidyll I did Google, and found a lot of different solutions on how to do this, and being super new to emacs I didn't know which method I should use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map ";" #'evil-ex)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map ":" #'evil-repeat-find-char)
```

Place it anywhere after you've loaded evil-mode.

EDIT: You can also use `evil-define-key` / `evil-define-key*`:

```lisp
(evil-define-key* 'motion 'global
  ";" #'evil-ex
  ":" #'evil-repeat-find-char)
```

The difference between `evil-define-key` and `evil-define-key*` is the latter will defer the keybinds under the motion keymap is available (if it isn't already).

You can find documentation on the function with `M-x describe-function RET evil-define-key*` or <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `describe-function` <kbd>RET</kbd>.